# 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, browser

**GET http://localhost:3000/data/posts.json  431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)**
I am getting an error mentioned above.
I am using local server **"npm server"** ***(No Xampp or WAMP)***

JSON file is downloaded from here **"https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users?_format=json&access-token=UrX-V34IN7O-1TV0HEaVUCRUz65B9-ibL6M1"**
I have downloaded this file on the local server.

My Code is:

const API = './data/posts.json';

```
componentDidMount(){

        fetch(API)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then( (data) => { console.log("data - ", data) } )
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to delete all the saved cookies for your localhost:3000. Because if you start your 10 different projects at "localhost:3000" and if each saves cookie, everytime you make a request, all those cookies will be attached to the `req` object

1-chrome settings

2-on the left menu, click on Privacy and security tab

3-go to "privacy and security" section

4-click on site settings

5-click "view permissions and data stored across sites"

6-find localhost and on the right menu reset data

Comment: Using CRA locally on port 3000, I was getting this error.  You saved me a tonne of time yilmaz! Thank you

Comment: Using Next.js with AWS Amplify and you helped me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Clearing site data from browser worked for me:

> Go to console -> select application -> Clear Storage -> Clear Site Data

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node v12.x.x, then try to upgrade it to v14.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error because I was calling an API before my document load, so I was passing jwt_token in the header and so my API was called before JWT TOKEN assignment.

I was using JQuery:

This was my previous code:

```
let manager_list_cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("manager_list_cache"));

    if (manager_list_cache && manager_list_cache.length > 0) {
        manager_list = manager_list_cache
    } else {
        // rendering managers
        getMethod(jwt_token, '/api/manager/all_manager/')
            .then(data => {
                localStorage.setItem("manager_list_cache", JSON.stringify(data));
            })//api.js
    }
```

And this is my latest code, I wrapped it in document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let manager_list_cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("manager_list_cache"));

    if (manager_list_cache && manager_list_cache.length > 0) {
        manager_list = manager_list_cache
    } else {
        // rendering managers
        getMethod(jwt_token, '/api/manager/all_manager/')
            .then(data => {
                localStorage.setItem("manager_list_cache", JSON.stringify(data));
            })//api.js
    }
})
```

As you can see my getMethod() is looking strange but I'm using some function behind, so I have to pass only JWT TOKEN and API to make a call