# 431 - (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

**First time posting a question please keep it in mind when reading**

**Things i tried:** Cleared my google chrome cache and cookies, tried incognito mode, updated my node to the latest version still getting the same error.

**Error I'm Getting chrome:** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

**auth.js:22** doubt its relevant but source in dev tools Giving me the error at fetch part

```
export const authInit = data => {
      const { user, type } = data;
      let url;
      if (type === "Login") {
        url = "/api/auth/login";
      } else if (type === "Register") {
        url = "/api/auth/register";
      }
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.LOADING });
        return fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(user),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.success) {
              return dispatch(authError(response.messages));
            }
```

Comment: Did you start your server ?

Comment: @xMayank yes ofcourse

Comment: hey @92yo i am facing same issue can you help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625785/431-request-header-fields-too-large

Answer (score 4):

Maybe should you try this.

It's talking about an error about node js header size :

[article](https://cri.dev/posts/2020-05-18-Fixing-431-Request-Header-Fields-Too-Large-in-Nodejs/)

You should run node with `--max-http-header-size=16384` for eg.

If you run the server with `npm start`, so just modify the script in the `package.json`

---

Maybe another problem with the body parser of express ?

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser(){limit:5000kb})
```

You can find the doc [here](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) about body options

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, still gives me same error.

Comment: Maybe with body-parser ?

Comment: Tried doing that still returns same error.  and now im getting an **unexpected end of JSON input** along with the 431 code.

Comment: What's the node command you're running? I needed to order the command like this in order to get node to pick up the flag: `node --max-http-header-size=16384 index.js`.